# Tool like SuperCache for Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, performance, memory

[SuperCache](http://superspeed.com/desktop/supercache.php) sounds interesting but it's for Windows XP only. I am not sure if if this kind of software could be beneficial under Windows 7 or if Windows 7 already does similar stuff with its own caching. The fact that all hard drive I/O is delayed and reads and writes are done in memory first sounds appealing.

I use Visual Studio a lot which does a lot of I/O operations and would love to speed it up. I will have lots of RAM soon. Note this software is not Ram Disk where you define a logical drive and you put stuff in there. SuperCache is about putting the OS files and anything loaded in memory so it's fetched from memory instead of from the hard drive which is slower. SuperCache sounds more versatile.

Is there a similar tool for Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

Old question I know, but SuperCache is now available for [Windows 7 (32-bit and 64-bit)](http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/supercache.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a USB drive, you may want to try the ReadyBoost functionality that is part of Windows 7.  This uses the flash drive to add extra memory for applications such as virtual machines or IDEs.

Here is some documented discussion on improvements to Visual Studio using ReadyBoost:

http://jeffmixon.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!6A5A371814D7B929!129.entry?sa=675260251

About Readyboost:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/readyboost

Comment: I already have lots of memory. More than what all the opened apps need. ReadyBoost addresses low memory situations.